# Wordpress: How to use a different comment from for reply_link

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I am wondering if it is possible to use 2 different comment forms in Wordpress `comment.php` and `reply.php`. The first one would be to write a comment for the post. The second form would be used to reply to a comment. I want to have both forms customized differently and not reuse the same form as comment for the reply link.

I don't see how I can achieve this looking at the function?

```
comment_reply_link(array_merge($args,
  array(
    'depth'     => $depth, 
    'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'])
  )
)
```

Anyone ever achieved this?

Comment: well wordpress provide by default to add the comment form below the comment you want to reply to, as long as(as stated in the documentary) "If JavaScript is enabled and the comment-reply.js JavaScript is loaded the link moves the comment form to just below the comment."-http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link

Comment: Yes, I want the comment form to move up to where you press the reply link, but I would want the form to change to reply.php

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/ ?